# Strange Error in transporting a Mobile Agent

Tags: deserialization, agents-jade

I have written a code for Mobility of an Agent. It works fine with a 
 Wireless (via Router) Link
But when I created an Ad-Hoc Wireless Connection with my friend's laptop it failed. This is the error I got: 
`Jan 27, 2012 12:06:37 PM jade.core.mobility.AgentMobilityService$CommandSourceSi
nk handleInformMoved
SEVERE: Error creating agent on destination container. Abort transfer. An I/O er
ror occurred during de-serialization [nested java.io.InvalidClassException: jade
.core.Agent$1; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -85
03980205419088695, local class serialVersionUID = -6369687405671300436]`
Since the program worked fine with one network connection, it failed with the same source on a different computer and a different connection.

1. What does this error mean? De-serilization error if any should have come in the first case as well
2. Is the type of connection i.e. Ad-Hoc a root of the problem?
3. OR is it due to the code, which includes File Access commands that is causing the problem (then why did it work in the first case)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the serialized object's serialVersionUID is different from the class on the other JVM. For this give some fixed Long value. If you are using eclipse then add generated serial version ID to every class that implements Serializable. Clean and rebuild the source code. If you are just using command line then do

```
serialver "AgentClass"
```

and use the value generated from it and recompile the source code.

Comment: i can manually change the SerialUID of my computer where I am compiling the Agent Code, how do I change the SerialUID of a say unknown destination host? Is there any java library which allows me to auto-set the serialUID to any value?

Comment: then what is the purpose of the mobile agent if i am distributing the code across a distributed platform? is there any other way?

Comment: Even though the containers may be different on different hosts but you initialize agent objects corresponding to the same agent class right?

Comment: i think there is a communication gap: I will put my question right as it is: I have written a mobile agent code which moves to another PC and executes it over there using doMove(destination). But I am getting this serialversionUID error because serialversionUID's for different PC's are different. Then what option do i have:
1. explicitly change the serialUID from the code itself
2. manually change the serialUID's of all the PC's
which is a better option?

Comment: To explain the whole process, First let us assume that AgentClass has no ID. when you call doMove() the AgentClass Object is serialized and stamped with a ID(some random ID). On the other JVM when it tries to deserialize the AgentClass Object it will compare with AgentClass that it is using for deserializing. It might be old or new. If it does not match then you will get an error. So for this the best way is to provide atleast the first time with a fixed ID and however many times the AgentClass changes no JVM will know it. Because the ID remains the same.

Comment: ok a last Q, you mean i should insert a  static final long serialVersionUID = <some value> in my code and then re-compile and execute right? This will solve my problem ?